# Timer in control off hardware, making the flash stady

Tags: android, timer, camera, sleep

I am new to Java / Android. I am developing an application for a school project, where I need to turn the blitz/flash from the camera on and off, like a strobe light, and I need to control how long it is on and off, right now I use `Thread.sleep();` to control the wait time, but that is not accurate enough. I would like to use some type of timer maybe `System.nanotime()`, but I do not know a good way to use this, can any of you hackers help me?

I have tried this. hope there are a better way.

```
public void waiton(int ms){
    long t0 = System.nanoTime()+ ms*1000000;
    while(t0 > System.nanoTime()){

    }
}
```

instead of sleep.

```
Threat.sleep(5);
```

I want to see how fast i can make a steady strobe light, it is not a strobe light i want in the end, but i want to see how fast i can make it. it is for a study! :P.

Here you can see the code i am working on.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class FlashActivity extends Activity {

public Camera cam = Camera.open();

int i = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.flashview);

    final Button onbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.onbutton);
    final Button offbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.offbutton);

    final Switch switchonoff = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switch1);

    onbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i = 1;

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

                    Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters(), p2 = cam.getParameters();

                    p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    p2.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

                    cam.startPreview();
                    cam.cancelAutoFocus();
                    //cam.autoFocus(null);

                    while (i == 1){
                    cam.setParameters(p);

                    waiton(10);

                    cam.setParameters(p2);

                    waitoff(10);

                    }
                }

              }).start();   
        }
    });

    offbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i = 0;
            cam.stopPreview();          

        }
    });

    switchonoff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Switch nv = (Switch)v;
        if(nv.isChecked()){
            i = 1;

        }else{
            i = 0;

        }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    cam.stopPreview();
    i = 0;

    if (cam != null) {
        cam.release();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onStop();

    cam.stopPreview();

    if (cam != null) {
        cam.release();
    }
}

public void waiton(int ms){
    long t0 = System.nanoTime()+ ms*1000000;
    while(t0 > System.nanoTime()){

    }
}

public void waitoff(int ms){
    long t1 = System.nanoTime()+ ms*1000000;
    while(t1 > System.nanoTime()){

    }
}
};
```

Ignore the switch, right now i  am converting from 2 buttons to a switch. But i want the flash to work before, i make some more changes to it.

If some of you have a way to control the blitz/flash without using the camera, that works for all newer android phones. That would be perfect.

I have some problems with auto-focus, that throw a error ones in a while, this may make my program more unstable, something with that the focus areal can not be 0,0,0,0, and do not know what i should change it to.

Later when it works, I think I will convert it to a state machine, to get some more functionality out of it. If it is possible for me :p.

Comment: From your question it seems like you need someone to write code for you. I suggest that explain what you have tried, so that u can get targeted help.

Comment: android is not the good platform for this, as it is not RT

Comment: I just gained privilege to comment, can someone with high reputation like @AndroSelva please move my answer to comments?

Comment: Can you gave us more information about what exactly you want to do? because a nanosecond is such a small time, what precision and what job you want to do?

Comment: I want nanosecond to make the time light to be on and off the the same period of time, this is not implemented yet. And I saw in a study/article on the net that nanoTime was more "accurate". [Article](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/171774/getting_high_precision_timing_on_.php?print=1)